# Changing values of dictionary to integers

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently setting up a dictionary and am attempting to convert the values associated with a key from strings to integers. So I'm trying to go from this:

```
    {'Georgia': ['18', '13', '8', '14']}
```

To this:

```
    {'Georgia': [18, 13, 8, 14]}
```

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try to look this up at all? http://stackoverflow.com/q/379906/2615940 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4291236/2615940

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

`map` is taking the values from the iterable in this case the value of the dictionaries key and casting every item in the iterable to an `int`. `map` returns a map object instead of a `list` so we are converting it back to a list.

```
a_dict = {'Georgia': ['18', '13', '8', '14']}
a_dict['Georgia'] = list(map(int, a_dict['Georgia']))
```

Or, if you need to convert multiple values this way you can use a loop:

```
 for k,v in list(a_dict.items()):
     a_dict[k] = list(map(int, v))
```

Comment: Like Raymond's answer, you should add some comments or explanation of how the code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> old =  {'Georgia': ['18', '13', '8', '14']}
>>> new = {key: list(map(int, value)) for key, value in old.items()}
>>> new
{'Georgia': [18, 13, 8, 14]}
```

Comment: It would be good to add an explanation of why and how this works.