# Altering string using a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

**Background**

I am using NeuroNER  http://neuroner.com/ to label text data `sample_string` as seen below.

`sample_string = 'Patient Jane Candy was seen by Dr. Smith on 12/1/2000 and her number is 1111112222'`

**Output (using NeuroNER)**

My output is a list of dictionary `dic_list`

```
dic_list = [
 {'id': 'T1', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 8, 'end': 11, 'text': 'Jane'},    
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 13, 'end': 17, 'text': 'Candy'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DOCTOR', 'start': 35, 'end': 39, 'text': 'Smith'},  
 {'id': 'T4', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 44, 'end': 52, 'text': '12/1/2000'},   
 {'id': 'T5', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 72, 'end': 81, 'text': '1111112222'}]
```

**Legend**

`id` = text ID

`type` = type of text being identified

`start` = starting position of identified text

`end` =  ending position of identified text

`text` = text that is identified

**Goal**

Since the location of the `text`(e.g. `Jane`) is given by `start` and `end`, I would like to change each `text` from `dic_list` to `**BLOCK**` in my list `sample_string`

**Desired Output**

`sample_string = 'Patient **BLOCK**  **BLOCK** was seen by Dr. **BLOCK**  on **BLOCK** and her number is **BLOCK**`

**Question**

I have tried [Replacing a character from a certain index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752946/replacing-a-character-from-a-certain-index) and [Edit the values in a list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291236/edit-the-values-in-a-list-of-dictionaries) but they are not quite what I am looking for

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Please show the actual code you have tried to use and explain what specifically didn't work.

Comment: note: the start and end don't seem to match the length of "text" in some fields, or the position in the file.

Comment: `dic_list` has been updated. My apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution based on the `start` and `end` indexes,

you can use the intervals *between* those is dic_list, to know which parts you need. then join them with `**BLOCK**`.

try this:

```py
sample_string = 'Patient Jane Candy was seen by Dr. Smith on 12/1/2018 and her number is 5041112222'

dic_list = [
 {'id': 'T1', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 8, 'end': 11, 'text': 'Jane'},
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 13, 'end': 17, 'text': 'Candy'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DOCTOR', 'start': 35, 'end': 39, 'text': 'Smith'},
 {'id': 'T4', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 44, 'end': 52, 'text': '12/1/2018'},
 {'id': 'T5', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 72, 'end': 81, 'text': '5041112222'}]

parts_to_take = [(0, dic_list[0]['start'])] + [(first["end"]+1, second["start"]) for first, second in zip(dic_list, dic_list[1:])] + [(dic_list[-1]['end'], len(sample_string)-1)]
parts = [sample_string[start:end] for start, end in parts_to_take]

sample_string = '**BLOCK**'.join(parts)

print(sample_string)
```

Comment: There is a slightly more readable way to do this, see [this solution](https://repl.it/repls/SelfreliantImpracticalNanotechnology).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse nice, working in-place on the input string itself.

Comment: That link may go dead but you can add it to your answer as another option. My answer uses replace and yours does start and end.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something but you can just use `.replace()`:

```
sample_string = 'Patient Jane Candy was seen by Dr. Smith on 12/1/2018 and her number is 5041112222'

dic_list = [
 {'id': 'T1', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 0, 'end': 6, 'text': 'Jane'},    
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 8, 'end': 11, 'text': 'Candy'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DOCTOR', 'start': 35, 'end': 39, 'text': 'Smith'},  
 {'id': 'T4', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 44, 'end': 52, 'text': '12/1/2018'},   
 {'id': 'T5', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 72, 'end': 81, 'text': '5041112222'}]

for dic in dic_list:
    sample_string = sample_string.replace(dic['text'], '**BLOCK**')
print(sample_string)
```

Though `regex` will probably be faster:

```
import re
sample_string = 'Patient Jane Candy was seen by Dr. Smith on 12/1/2018 and her number is 5041112222'

dic_list = [
 {'id': 'T1', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 0, 'end': 6, 'text': 'Jane'},    
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 8, 'end': 11, 'text': 'Candy'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DOCTOR', 'start': 35, 'end': 39, 'text': 'Smith'},  
 {'id': 'T4', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 44, 'end': 52, 'text': '12/1/2018'},   
 {'id': 'T5', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 72, 'end': 81, 'text': '5041112222'}]

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(dic['text'] for dic in dic_list))
result = pattern.sub('**BLOCK**', sample_string)
print(result)
```

Both output:

```
Patient **BLOCK** **BLOCK** was seen by Dr. **BLOCK** on **BLOCK** and her number is **BLOCK**
```

Comment: this will work unless there might be other parts of the text that match the parts to replace, that shouldn't be replaced. (e.g. someone named "seen" or something)

Comment: Yeah I'lll update it. Though if they are just removing sensetive information this should work. It would help if `start` and `end` lined up properly.

Answer (score 0):

per the suggestion of @ `Error - Syntactical Remorse`

```
sample_string = 'Patient Jane Candy was seen by Dr. Smith on 12/1/2018 and her number is 5041112222'

dic_list = [
 {'id': 'T1', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 8, 'end': 11, 'text': 'Jane'},
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PATIENT', 'start': 13, 'end': 17, 'text': 'Candy'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DOCTOR', 'start': 35, 'end': 39, 'text': 'Smith'},
 {'id': 'T4', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 44, 'end': 52, 'text': '12/1/2018'},
 {'id': 'T5', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 72, 'end': 81, 'text': '5041112222'}]

offset = 0
filler = '**BLOCK**'
for dic in dic_list:
    sample_string = sample_string[:dic['start'] + offset ] + filler + sample_string[dic['end'] + offset + 1:]
    offset += dic['start'] - dic['end'] + len(filler) - 1
print(sample_string)
```